# Unable to reach the textarea by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Elements]

I'm trying to get the text from the textarea "sn-chat-textarea". I'm using interval function but in console I see the output -> "S.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]". Could anyone assist with what I'm doing wrong.

```
setInterval(function(){
var textInp = $('.sn-chat-textarea');
console.log(textInp); 
},2000);
```

Comment: use `$('.sn-chat-textarea').val()`

Comment: Thanks, but I get undefined as output.

Comment: your textarea has `value` attribute but doesn't have any value  try adding `value="somthing"` see if that works.

Comment: `$('.sn-chat-textarea')` gives you a jquery object/collection - you have to do something *with* that, eg `.val()` - also try `console.log(textInp.length)` to see if your selector is matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use val() function to get content of textarea.

```js
setInterval(function()
{
    var textInp = $('.sn-chat-textarea').val();
    console.log(textInp); 
},2000);
```

```html
<textarea class="sn-chat-textarea"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var textInp = $('.sn-chat-textarea').val();
  console.log(textInp);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea class="sn-chat-textarea">This is default</textarea>
```